# PHP HipHop + rewrite to index.php

Tags: php, hhvm

I wasted many hours to find, how to redirect all requests to index.php.

I mean:
site.com/some-url?param&1

will become

site.com/index.php and $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] === some-url?param&1

I've one hip hop archive (based on Nette Framework) and one virtualhost (one hiphop isntance proxied from Nginx).

Edit:
Alternative question can be: how to setup nginx to modify REQUEST_URI field sent to PHP over FastCGI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a rewrite rule to the main config.hdf file. hhvm does not support reading .htaccess files.

```
 # In my app I have a public side and and admin 
 # side. All requests to the public side should 
 # be rerouted through a script. All requests to
 # the backend .php and static asset files should
 # be allowed.

     * {

        # rewrite every request onto 
        # /myapp/page.php/<original request>

        pattern = ^(.*)$
        to = /myapp/page.php/$1

        # append any query strings.

        qsa = true
        }
```

I wrote [an article about configuring hhvm](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/fv-b-8-656/adventures-in-configuring-and-running-facebook-s-hiphopvm--hhvm--jit-compiler-for-php.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Nginx in front of HHVM then you probably want the static files to be served by Nginx (because it's faster) and everything else pass to `index.php`. In your Nginx site configuration you can do that as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with HipHop but .htaccess on Apache can take care of this with `RewriteRule`s

Comment: There is no .htaccess, because sources are in compiled archive. And I'm running on nginx. But thnaks :)